# Find String and append another string after it

Tags: php

I have a page with following code:

```
'customCode' => 'input name="last_name" id="last_name" size="25" maxlength="25" type="text" value="{$fields.last_name.value}"'
```

I want to run a script that will add `onblur="name_valid(this.value);"` after `name="last_name"`

Resulting Output should be like

```
'customCode' => 'input name="last_name" onblur="name_valid(this.value);" id="last_name" size="25" maxlength="25" type="text" value="{$fields.last_name.value}"
```

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. I assume adding `onblur=...` at the end of string doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

How about this,

```
$string = 'input name="last_name" id="last_name" size="25" maxlength="25" type="text" value="{$fields.last_name.value}"';

echo $string = str_replace('name="last_name"', 'name="last_name" onblur="name_valid(this.value);" ', $string);
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple string replace will do it.

```
<?php 
$input_str = '<input name="last_name" id="last_name" size="25" maxlength="25" type="text" value="{$fields.last_name.value}>'; 
$new_str= str_replace('name="last_name" ','name="last_name" onblur="name_valid(this.value);" ',$input_str);
echo $new_str; 
?>
```